# Xslt external parameter

Tags: java, xslt, parameters, external

In my server side

```
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer( 
                     new StreamSource("mytext.xsl"));
transformer.setParameter("parametro","hope");
transformer.transform( new DOMSource(document), outputStream );
```

--mytext.xslt--

. . .

. . .

why the value of $parametro isn't "hope" in my html output? 
Thanks

Comment: Your XSL has a <xsl:param> element to match we assume?

Answer (score 0):

yes in my xslt there is

```
  <xsl:param name="parametro"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$parametro"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"hope"` is an xpath expression, and if you need to pass a string value, you need to quote the value as `"'hope'"`. This is true at least for libxslt.